# passing single element inside array to jinja macro

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

I have a common jinja macro for checking array of strings and return 0 or 1 based on that.
But when i pass a single element inside an array( it is not going as array of string )

**sample code:**

```
{{ test_macro('code', ('02')) }} some_f
```

Macro code:

```
{% macro test_macro(
  col_name=column_name,
  codes=list_of_codes
) %}
{{ log("Codes:" ~ codes, True) }}
    case
      when {{ col_name }} in {{ codes }} then 1
      else 0
    end
{% endmacro %}
```

**Compiled code is something like this**

```
case
      when code in 02 then 1
      else 0
end
```

**instead of**

```
case
      when code in ('02') then 1
      else 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will always return the compiled code you shared, even if the list of strings that you pass has more than one value.

One option that you have is to change the macro with the following:

```
{% macro test_macro(col_name, codes=[]) %}

    case
      when {{ col_name }}
        {%- if codes|length > 1 %}
          in (
          {%- for code in codes -%}
            '{{ code }}'
            {%- if not loop.last -%}
              ,
            {%- endif -%}
            {%- if loop.last -%}
              )
            {%- endif -%}
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          = {{ codes[0] }}
        {%- endif %}
          then 1
      else 0
    end

{% endmacro %}
```

So that when you run the macro like this:
`{{ test_macro('code', ['2']) }}`

It will compile as:

```
    case
      when code
          = 02
          then 1
      else 0
    end
```

Whereas if you add more `codes`, as in:
`{{ test_macro('code', ['2', '3']) }}`

dbt will compile as:

```
    case
      when code
          in ('2','3')
        then 1
      else 0
    end
```

Note that, when calling the macro, you will need to enclose your second argument (the `codes`) in brackets.

Comment: the length is coming as 2, when i send the code as ('02') - i already tried the length, because of this issue , i could not use that.. I'm not sure why length is 2? maybe its considering as integer instead of Array of Strings

Comment: Also, when i print the list of codes ( when i send ('02') ), its printing as 02 instead of ('02') - this is the main reason the length is coming as 2

Comment: Ah my bad, did not try that case. I think it will then be better to use an array instead of a tuple (also not sure why ('02') is coming as length > 0. Will update the answer :)